# Replace all occurences of string in multiple source files in Intellij

Tags: replace, intellij-idea, search-engine

Is it possible? 
2 options is preferable : 
1) with variable 
2) other string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The command is named "Replace in path" (Ctrl-Shift-R in my keyboard shortcut preferences).

You could have found it yourself by typing Ctrl-shift-A, and typing "replace": this will list all the commands containing the word "replace" in their name.