# How to replace java code block to another code block automatically or pragramatically?

Tags: java, regex, awk, sed, text-processing

I have many java source files in which I want to change a code block to another code block in every java files that I have in my project.

e.g. 
My project has about 300 java source file and every file has this code block

```
while (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    p.nextToken();
    field = p.getCurrentName();
    obj.populateFromJsonString(field, p);
}
```

I want to replace this code block to

```
while (p.nextToken() != null) {
    field = p.getCurrentName();
    if(field!=null){
        obj.populateFromJsonString(field, p);
    }
}
```

in all the java files. object `obj` in code block is different for different files

I know somehow this can be done by text processing with [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). I am thinking for alternate solution the way compilers read and parse java source file. there may be some application based on this way for solving my problem.

Please share way or application to solve this problem. sed/awk based solutions are also welcome.

Comment: That's not DRY. I'd think about how to refactor that into a method that you can modify once and call many times.  A serious IDE like IntelliJ can do it.

Comment: I have updated my question that object `obj` in code block is different for different file

Comment: and there are more than 300 file so I need to automat it so I guess IDE wont help me

Comment: why not using java for that, for example problem is easy solvable in python

Comment: yes this can be solvee by python or any other programming language which support file input output. for python we can use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput) module for in-place editing.

Comment: You can do it in multiple files: replace in path.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086759/replace-all-occurences-of-string-in-multiple-source-files-in-intellij

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to use an IDE to do this, but if you really wanted to use sed, put this in a file called j.sed

```
/while (p\.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken\.END_OBJECT) {/{
    :loop
    n
    /}/b    
    s/field = p\.getCurrentName();/if (field!=null) {/
    s/p\.nextToken();/field = p\.getCurrentName();/
    s/...\.populateFromJsonString(field, p);/\t&\n\t}/
    b loop
}
```

Then use in the command line

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i.bak -f j.sed {} \;
```

This will on input:

```
while (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    p.nextToken();
    field = p.getCurrentName();
    obj.populateFromJsonString(field, p);
}
```

Output this:

```
while (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    field = p.getCurrentName();
    if (field!=null) {
        obj.populateFromJsonString(field, p);
    }
}
```

The -i.bak will edit in place and store a backup as filename.java.bak

Answer (score -2):

How about this

```
$ searchvar=`cat searchblock.txt`  
$ replvar=`cat replblock.txt`  

$ sed -i ":loop; $! N; tloop;  s/$searchvar/$replvar/g" *.java
```

where in `searchblock.txt` you'll put inputblock so on, with `*.java` you will catch all java files in folder

notice `` ` `` is not `'`

be careful while testing for `-i` inplace editing, you can try with backup file(s)